# Select an element that satisfies a condition

Tags: python, performance, list, python-3.x

I would like to select a specific element that satisfies a condition from a (very long) list. In my specific case each item in the list is a class and the condition I want is, for example, item.id == 1.

I started with

```
[item for item in collection if item.id == 1]
```

but I don't want to traverse the whole list because I am sure there is only one element that satisfied the condition.

The other option is

```
def check(collection):
    for item in collection:
        if item.id == 1:
            return item
```

Is there a more efficient way? Does Python 3 have a build in function for that?
Another option could be to preprocess the list in order to obtain a dictionary, e.g.

```
{item.id : item for item in collection}
```

Comment: Could you add the class to another list when the item.id is changed to 1?

Comment: No, I can't id. I have a list of such elements and I need to select a specific one. If I add each element to a new list I would have `len(collecion)` new lists with 1 element each

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) and the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
item = next((item for item in collection if item.id == 1), None)
```

This'll find the *first* matching element in the collection, or return `None` if there is no match. It'll not iterate and evaluate any more than is strictly required to find that one element.

However, if you do need to do this a lot, creating the mapping just once then querying that each time is going to be more efficient:

```
mapping = {item.id: item for item in collection}
item = mapping.get(1)
```

as that'll limit looping to just once, then use the O(1) lookup performance. It is a memory-vs-speed trade-off.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first element that satisfies a condition, use `next()` as outlined in [the ninja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040117/select-an-element-that-satisfies-a-condition/27040132#27040132).

To get an element that satisfies a condition *and check that it's the only one such,* I use the following function:

```
def single(seq):
    """Checks that the sequence has a single element and returns it."""
    """Analogous to .Net LINQ's Single()"""
    if hasattr(seq,"__len__"):
        assert len(seq)==1
        return seq[0]
    else:
        i=iter(seq)
        try: value=i.next()
        except StopIteration: raise AssertionError()
        try: i.next()
        except StopIteration: return value
        else: raise AssertionError()
```